# Meditatively crazy

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

> Yes, ommmm... Eee! Sea! Rye! Pea! Toe! Gee, ram.

What do you make of that?

**Backstory:**

I've just escaped from an asylum where I've stayed for the past ten years, and I'm a little excited about everything. I don't want to go back anytime soon, and meditating calms me down a little. But sometimes, just sometimes, I start acting looney again. What do you make of that?

Comment: Is the word **ram** in the given series of words or is it with Gee ?

Comment: I think I have the puzzle half-solved. Is this possible or is it an all-or-nothing sort of deal?

Comment: @ABcDexter I don't understand. Everything in the blockquote is together.

Comment: @TheMadHaberdasher It is possible to have pieces. Post what you have and I'll tell you if you're heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

<strike>I only have part of it so far, but...</strike> Okay I think I have it now?

> Reading "Yes, ommmm... Eek! Sea! Rye! Pea! Toe! Gee, ram." as alternating multi-letter sounds/single-letter names gives the letters "YS|M|EEK|C|RY|P|TO|G|RAM", the latter part of which is obviously the word "cryptogram", a pretty meta description of the puzzle itself. The first part is slightly more confusing, but I'd wager the Y is meant to be pronounced as a letter as well, producing the phrase "Wise Meek Cryptogram". Which kind of fits the meditation theme?

Comment: Could it be S, Make C?

Comment: Very close! My interpretation of  "eek" was a sound like "eee!"

Answer (score 3):

This can be a coincidence

Literally reading it in Hindi Pronunciation (Other devanagari puzzlers can confirm)

> SOM, EK SI RAI PEA TOH JI, RAM

Extracting Meaning

> SOM -> It is a liquor drink https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soma

.

> EK -> One https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Hindi/Numbers

.

> SI -> Like

.

> RAI -> Opinion

.

> PEA -> Drink

.

> TOH -> then

.

> JI -> Live

.

> RAM -> Gods Name -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama

.
Inferring

> OPINION is IF YOU DRINK SOM, YOU LIVE LIKE GOD.

Comment: The method is partially correct, but unfortunately, I don't understand Hindi.

Comment: Thanks @Illyasviel. Hope other "Hindi" understanding puzzlers corroborate what I have written. Meanwhile Am still trying alternatives and probably correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is

> Yes, A meek cryptogram.

Because

Yes

> Obvious

Ommmm..

> Ommmm sounds like ahmmmmm,  plus eak! combines to form A meek - meek means subtle, imposed

Sea

> Letter C

Rye

> Rye sounds like arrr , why  (RY)

Pea

> Letter P

Toe

> Whole sound, in crypTOgram

Gee, Ram

> Whole sound, in cryptoGRAM

Meaning

> The whole phrase would be 'Yes, A subtle or imposed cryptogram'

disclaimer:

> Now if the phrase "Yes, A meek cryptogram, is a cryptogram for something else entirely, youve got me

Comment: convincing !!! great !!!

Comment: You are so close! I admit, my interpretation for "eek" is a slight stretch. It should have been "eee!"